# How to get cost for a query in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, how can we get the cost for a given query? We are doing a lot of high-compute queries -- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute -- which often multiplies the data processed by 2 or more.

Is there a way to get the "Cost" of a query with the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the API or the [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quickstart-command-line) you could use the flat `--dry_run` which validates the query instead of running it, like so:

```
cat ../query.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=False --dry_run
```

Output:

> Query successfully validated. Assuming the tables are not modified,
>   running this query will process 9614741466 bytes of data.

For costs, just divide the total bytes by `1024 ^ 4`, multiply the result by `5` and then multiply by the `Billing Tier` you are in and you have the expected cost ($0.043 in this example).

If you already ran the query and want to know how much it processed, you can run:

```
bq show -j (job_id of your query)
```

And it'll return Bytes Billed and Billing Tier (looks like you still have to do the math for cost computation).

For WebUI, you can install [BQMate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) and it already estimates costs for you (but you still have to adapt for your Billing Tier).

As a final recommendation, sometimes it's possible to greatly improve performance of analyzes just by optimizing how the query process data (here at our company we had several high computing queries that now process data normally just by using features such as [ARRAYS and STRUCTS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#arrays_and_structs) for instance).

Comment: additionally, you can get this in the WebUI -- under Job Information -- after the query has been run.